# Navigation drawer will close even if overwrite onBackPressed()

Tags: android, back-button, navigation-drawer

Is there a way to prevent navigation drawer from closing when back button is pressed? For testing purpose I make the call to `onBackPressed()` empty

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

but the navigation drawer still responds to the back button and close. Other cases the back button is non-responsive as I expected. What should I overwrite in order to prevent navigation drawer from closing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call in onCreate() in your activity

```
mDrawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

and handle the closing/opening logic yourself in OnBackPressed().

Comment: I found out that it is better to do this on onResume; somehow when I came back to my app, the navigationdrawer got recreated and without this setting. It happend several times and it is fixed since I moved this to onResume. Thanks for your answer though!